# How I can print specific html that generated by one of the functions?

Tags: javascript, html, printing

For example, I have this function:

```
function getPrintedHTML()
{
    //...
    return some_html_code;
}
```

I know I can print whole page with `window.print()`, but it prints whole page.
Anything can be done to print the function result?

P.S. print without adding this html to body.

Comment: @Collett89 - but I need to print it, not output it.

Comment: Add the returned HTML to the page, hide all other elements from printer (you can also hide the newly created HTML from screen), print, and finally remove the newly-created HTML. Afaik it's not possible to print elements which are not in the text flow.

Comment: load it into an iframe and print the iframe.

Comment: @Teemu - how I can hide all other elements from printer with JS? Ok, I can recursively walk through them, but what I need to set?

Comment: No JS needed, prepare the page with [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). `media` attribute in `style` and `link` tags works in older browsers too.

Comment: @Teemu - but if I really want to hide those with JS, what I should set to `element.style.`?

Comment: I doubt it's possible to hide elements from printer only using inline styles, not sure though. Anyway, it's simplest to do it with style sheets.

Comment: @Teemu - Ok, thank you. I hope it works for IE6 - IE8 too.

Comment: `media` attribute works even in IE5 : ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try an `iframe`:

```
var i = document.createElement('iframe');
i.onload = function() {
    i.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = someHtml;
    i.contentWindow.print();
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.removeChild(i);
    }, 0);
};
document.body.appendChild(i);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h4t1o978/)

Comment: Thank you. Good it does not requires extra CSS

Answer (score 0):

you can Hide the other elements in the page by hidding it as put the rest data in one div and make the div false on the above function